# Changing TR class does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the TR className with javascript, why it doesn't seem to work (note : must work also for IE8)

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    tr.test {background-color:#000000;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}
  </style>
  <script>
  _table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  _tbody = _table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  _tr = _tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  _tr.className="test";
  </script>
</head>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>

</table>
</html>
```

Comment: place this `script`  before closing` </body>` tag, or in some kind of `window load` event and it will work

Comment: That is quite a bit more code than you need. After you fetch the table, you can get its descendants very easily: `_table.tBodies[0].rows[0].className="test";`

Comment: Or use: `document.querySelector("table>tbody>tr").className="test";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code after `table` tag

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    tr.test {background-color:#000000;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>

</table>
<script>
  _table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  _tbody = _table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
  _tr = _tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  _tr.className="test";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```